How to fetch AWS Elastic IP quota(limit) and find out how many IP elastic addresses my terraform script can create
I am fairly new to AWS CLI. I am trying to find out the limit(quota) of elastic IP addresses for a region(e.g. us-east-1). From that limit, how many have been used and how many are remaining for my terraform script to use. I need to use this to conditionalise the further flow. Need help. Right now I have tried to use the below but it gives me wrong answer.
Available_Elastic_IPs=$(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=$AWS_SESSION_TOKEN aws ec2 describe-addresses --query "Addresses[?NetworkInterfaceId == null ].PublicIp" --region "$REGION" --output "text" | wc -w)

This tells me where the network interface ID are null. Even if the count is 0, I can still go ahead and create EC2 instances with elastic IPs. So I think the query needs slight adjustment.

This is a minimal working example that I used to achieve what you're trying to :
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 5.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {}

data "aws_servicequotas_service_quota" "ip_addresses" {
  service_code = "ec2"
  quota_name = "EC2-VPC Elastic IPs"
}

output "vpc_quota" {
  value = data.aws_servicequotas_service_quota.ip_addresses
}

The output I added will look something like this
vpc_quota = {
  "adjustable" = true/false
  "arn" = "arn:aws:servicequotas:<REGION>:<ACCOUNT>:ec2/L-0263D0A3"
  "default_value" = 5
  "global_quota" = true/false
  "id" = "arn:aws:servicequotas:<REGION>::ec2/L-0263D0A3"
  "quota_code" = "L-0263D0A3"
  "quota_name" = "EC2-VPC Elastic IPs"
  "service_code" = "ec2"
  "service_name" = "Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2)"
  "usage_metric" = tolist([<...>])
  "value" = <THE VALUE YOU'RE LOOKING FOR>
}

Some docs that I used that may be helpful to you:

aws_servicequotas_service_quota docs
Elastic IP address quota docs.

To get the quota name I followed the AWS docs instructions on the console and copy/pasted the quota_name that was shown there.

OK I am getting this error . Seems like I do not have the access to run the above. Will speak to the admin to assign me access policies. Will try after that
not authorized to perform: servicequotas:ListAWSDefaultServiceQuotas because no identity-based policy allows the servicequotas:ListAWSDefaultServiceQuotas action

Hi @Lorenzo , Thanks for this. I am able to get the quota limit in terraform. How to get the actually used and unused EIPs. Basically I want to check if I have sufficient EIPs to proceed or fail the script there only.

I think this is a separate question and you should ask a new question for this one, providing more details in there as to what you're trying to achieve and what you've tried so far

Thanks to @Lorenzo's answer, I was able to get through my problem. I combined all this and ran on Jenkins shell script and it worked.
Here is my EIP_Get_Quota.tf file
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 5.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region =  var.region
  access_key = var.aws_access_key_id
  secret_key = var.aws_secret_access_key 

}

data "aws_servicequotas_service_quota" "ip_addresses" {
  service_code = "ec2"
  quota_name = "EC2-VPC Elastic IPs"
}

output "vpc_quota" {
  value = data.aws_servicequotas_service_quota.ip_addresses
}




variable "aws_access_key_id" {

}
variable "aws_secret_access_key" {

}

variable "region"{
  default="us-east-1"
}

extracted the output with the help of below code in shell script
terraform init
cmd1="terraform apply --auto-approve -var     aws_access_key_id=\"$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID\" -var region=\"$REGION\" -var     aws_secret_access_key=\"$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY\""
eval "$cmd1"
terraform output -json > $outputFileName
total_quota=$(cat "$outputFileName" | jq -r '.vpc_quota.value.value')

Then I ran the below in AWS command line (CLI)
Created_Elastic_IPs_Temp=$(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY aws ec2 describe-addresses --query "Addresses[*].PublicIp" --region "$REGION" --output "text" )

Created_Elastic_IPs=$(echo $Created_Elastic_IPs_Temp | wc -w) #Separated for error checking

#This is where you get the remaining number of EIPs. 
Total_Available_EIPs="$((total_quota - Created_Elastic_IPs))"

